# Pull through featured image in a custom menu

Tags: post-thumbnails

Trying to pull through the featured image in a custom menu without a plugin so I can style it how I want.

This is the code I have so far;

```
<?php
$navMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items(6); /*/Pass Nav Menu_id or Name*/
$previousMenuParent = $level = 0;                         
foreach ($navMenu as $menu) {
    $level = 0;
    echo '<li style="background-image:url("");"><a href="'. $menu->url .'">'. $menu->title .'</a>';                            
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $menu->title = has_post_thumbnail($menu->object_id) ? get_the_post_thumbnail($menu->object_id, 'thumbnail') : $menu->title;
}
?>
```

I've also tried;

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($menu->ID);
```

I feel I'm so close but either get errors or nothing (or in the latest case just the title again)

Can anyone help get  me over the line please?

Comment: I'm not sure about the HTML or CSS but the PHP code should work. `menu->object_id` holds the assigned Post ID and `has_post_thumbnail( $menu->object_id )` should return whether or not that page/post has an uploaded featured image.

Comment: I did    echo has_post_thumbnail( $menu->object_id );   and nothing happened

Comment: Then you need to debug your code and figure out if `$menu` has a property of `object_id` and if `$menu->object_id` is the expected post ID. If not you need to print the entire `$navMenu` variable to ensure it holds what you expect. This code should be right which means there's something else wrong up the line.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help, I did print_r and got a lot back, it has     object_id

Comment: Check and see if the printed `object_id` is the same as what you expected the Post ID for that assigned item to be. If they're the same then your above code should work and we would need more information on where, when, and how it's being run. Is this inside a function? `header.php`? First thing's first, ensure your `object_id` is the same as the Post ID

Comment: The 'object_id' is 208 which is the same ID of the page.

It's in a template file and sits in the middle of the website etc.

Comment: Then I feel that nothing is wrong with the above code and you need to do some further debugging. `has_post_thumbnail( 208 );` should either fail or pass also if you have the featured image set. As far as I can tell thus far, this question is not really answerable.

Comment: I add `has_post_thumbnail( 208 );` and it came back with 1...

Comment: Just tried  `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( 208 );` and that brought the image through, so just need to swap 208 with the id of the page itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $navMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items(6);                                                    
    foreach ($navMenu as $menu) {                            
        echo '<li style="background-image:url( '. get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $menu->object_id ) .' )">';
        echo '<a href="'. $menu->url .'">'. $menu->title .'</a>';
    }
?>
```